# Given vectors v = [5, −1], b1 = [1, 1], and b2 = [1, −1] all written in the standard basis, what is v in the basis defined by b1 ​and b2?

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

### Given vectors v= [5, −1], b1 = [1, 1], and b2 = [1, −1] all written in the standard basis, what is v in the basis defined by b1 ​and b2?

**The solution is [2, 3], but I need to know how.**

> v in the same basis as b1 and b2 is [5,-1]
>
> but if v has to be defined in terms of b1 and b2, then
>
> vb = 2b1, 3b2 = [2, 3] because this vector v is now being shown with b1
> and b2 as new basis vectors.

I understand b1, but get confused how projection b2 gets calculated the way it does.

The solution provided completed projection b2 as follows:

> Proj. b2 = $\frac{v.b2}{|b2|^2}$ = $\frac{(5x1)+(-1x-1)}{-1^2 + (-1^2)}$ = $\frac{6}{2}$ = 3

How does b2 [1, -1] become [**-1**, -1] in the calculation?

And even still, shouldn't that equal -2, not 2? Giving answer -3, not 3?

I seem to calculate  1^2, + (-1^2) = 0, and arrive at 6/0, which obviously isn't right. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the denominator, the -1 is a **mistake**. There should not be a negative sign in front of the 1. In fact the writer acts as if there is no negative sign there.
- You're going wrong because you're doing $1^2+-1^2=0$. You should instead be doing $1^2+(-1)^2=2$

For the numerator, $b_2$ has **not** become (-1,-1). It simply dots $b_2$ with v.

$$\begin{split}v\cdot b_2&=\left(\begin{matrix}5\\-1\end{matrix}\right)\cdot \left(\begin{matrix}1\\-1\end{matrix}\right)\\
&=5*1+-1*-1\\&=6\end{split}$$

The correct calculation without all these errors looks like

$$\begin{split}\frac{5*1+-1*-1}{1^2+(-1)^2}
&=\frac 6 2\\&=3\end{split}$$

Comment: So the minus needs to be done before squaring the 1, gotcha! What about the numerator though? Why is it negative 1?

Comment: The dot product goes "horizontally". It goes across, 5 times the 1, and then below, -1 times the -1. These are in fact correct. The first negative 1 comes from the second element of , the second -1 comes from the second element of b2. It goes "first element of v" times "first element of 2" plus "second element of v" times "second element of 2". It's -1 x -1 because it's v[2] * b2[2]. Together, v[1]*b2[1]+v[2]*b2[2].

Comment: yes sorry, I had that figured, just making silly mistakes from looking at it for too long lol! So my problem was that I wasn’t performing the negative 1 before squaring on the denominator, providing me with 0.

Answer (score 4):

> Given vectors v = [5, −1], b1 = [1, 1], and b2 = [1, −1] all written in the standard basis, what is v in the basis defined by b1 ​and b2?

Suppose $v = r\times b_1 + s\times b_2.$

Then, looking first at the 1st component of the vectors $b_1, b_2$ and $v$ and then looking at the 2nd component, you have:

$r(1) + s(1) = 5$ and 
$r(1) + s(-1) = -1.$

Two linear equations in two unknowns.  Solve for $r$ and $s$.

Answer (score 3):

That's much too "sophisticated" for me!

To write v = [5, −1] in terms of b1 = [1, 1] and b2 = [1, −1] **means** to write [5, -1]= a[1, 1]+ b[1, -1].  We can write this as
[5, -1]= [a, a]+ [b, -b]= [a+ b, a- b].

So we want a+ b= 5 and a- b= -1.
Adding the two equation eliminates b: 2a= 4 so a= 2.
Then 2+ b= 5 so b= 3.

[5, -1]= 2[1, 1]+ 3[1, -1].